# k-means clustered data: how to label newly incoming data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a data set with labels that were produced by a k-means clustering algorithm. Now there is some data (with the same data structure) from another source and I wonder what is the most sensible way to label this new, yet unseen data? I was thinking about either

- calculating the distance to the prior k-means centroids and label the data to the the nearest centroids accordingly
- run a new algorithm (e.g. SVM) on the new data using the old data as the training set

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything about this particular problem. There are only a few questions about the general use of k-means as a classification model:

- [Can k-means clustering do classification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300830/can-k-means-clustering-do-classification)
- [How to segment new data with existing K-means model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131173/how-to-segment-new-data-with-existing-k-means-model)

Thanks in advance.

Uli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need SVM thing.First way is more convenient.If you are using sklearn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html there is an example here.`predict` function will do your job.